# Disable of coloring for ls on NTFS filesystems

Tags: ls, colors, ntfs-3g

I like to have the output of `ls` colored so I quickly can spot files of specific types, however I have a separate disk in my computer which uses a ntfs-3g filesystem, this means that everything has `rwxrwxrwx`.

Here is the output of `ls -l -a` in a sample directory with a few files.

[image: ugly directory]

As you can see everything is green and blocky and especially the directories look out of place.

I would like for a way to either have coloring from file attributes disabled on ntfs-3g or completely disable coloring on ntfs-3g filesystems.

The difficult part of this is to localize these colorization changes to ntfs-3g file systems.

If it's not possible to localize to ntfs-3g filesystems directly, it would be fine for me to manually specify the path to the mount points.

---

Entry in for the ntfs filesystem in `/etc/fstab`

```
/dev/sdb1 /media/DATA ntfs-3g rw,users,noauto,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

I'm running debian sid.

Comment: THere is a simple method you can apply. `ls -fl` will do what you want.

Comment: @val0x00ff It is ofcourse a solution to pass the f flag, I was however wondering if it was possible to configure this to happen in some file so I don't have to use a flag

Comment: Kristoffer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/208345/dircolors-ls-not-being-displayed-correctly-under-ntfs-drive

Answer (score 6):

You could try giving more reasonable permissions:

```
/dev/sdb1 /media/DATA ntfs-3g rw,users,noauto,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=022 0 0
```

You can have more fine-grained control using `fmask` and `dmask`, IIRC, but `umask` should be enough.

Comment: I had the same issue as the OP and this worked well for me.